# Crear sección o div html dinamicamente

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de crear dinamicamente una sección de un portal web.

El tema es el siguiente; cree un editor de texto, la idea es que puedan escribir y una vez le den publicar (click en el boton) se re dirija a la misma pagina y me agregue el contenido en un div.

Formulario:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="frm-test" class="form-basic">
                <label><b>Autor:</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="txt-autor"  placeholder=" Tu Nombre..." required>
                <br>
                <br>
                <laber><b>Titulo:</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="txt-title"  placeholder=" Cuentos e Historias.." required>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea id="txt-content" name="txt-content"></textarea>
                </div>

                <center>
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-enviar" value="Publicar">
                </center>

              </form>
```

Como se ve el `action` del form lo deje vació para que cargue la misma pagina

script:

```
<?php

  $autor = NULL;
  $title = NULL;
  $cuento = NULL;

    if (!empty($_POST)) 
    {
        $autor = trim($_POST['txt-autor']);
        $title = trim($_POST['txt-title']);
        $cuento = trim($_POST['txt-content']);

        $date= strip_tags(date('Y-m-d'));

        echo"<script language='javascript'>document.getElementById('main-escritos').innerHTML = '<hr><div class='resume-item d-flex flex-column flex-md-row'><div class='resume-content mr-auto'><h3 class='mb-0'><?php echo $title  ?></h3><div class='subheading mb-3'><?php echo $autor  ?></div><p><?php echo $cuento ?></p></div><div class='resume-date text-md-right'><span class='text-primary'><?php echo $date ?></span><br><br><br>   <div class='addthis_inline_share_toolbox'></div>  </div></div><hr>';
            </script>;";    

    }

?>
```

Y este es el escript que estoy utilizando.

esta es la parte de la seccion que no me esta actualizando:

```
  <section class="resume-section p-3 p-lg-5 d-flex flex-column" id="escritos">
    <div class="my-auto">
      <h2 class="mb-5">escritos</h2>
      <hr>

  <div id="main-escritos">          
      <div class="resume-item d-flex flex-column flex-md-row">
        <div class="resume-content mr-auto">
          <h3 class="mb-0">Nota No.2</h3>
          <div class="subheading mb-3">Andres Diaz</div>
          <p> Señorita, con seguridad no le importe y tal vez ni quiera saberlo, pero no se llega a imaginar como la pienso y la extraño, las cosas pasaron diferente a como ambos pensábamos que serian, pero igual agradezco el poco o mucho tiempo que compartimos, sin duda grabó en mí demasiados recuerdos.<br>
          <br>
          <p>Tenia razón en muchas cosas, la mas importante de ellas es que usted realmente vale la pena.<br>
          Si pudiera volver a tras , las cosas serian diferentes, pero no puedo;  cargo con ello al estar ausente de su vida.
          Solo quiero que sepa que usted no fue un capricho y nunca lo sera.<br>
          Con el mayor cariño y afecto....<br>
          <br>
          Nadie.... por que nada fuimos.<br>
          A.</p>            
        </div>
        <div class="resume-date text-md-right">
        <span class="text-primary">Marzo 2018</span>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
            <!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
            <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox"></div>            
        </div>            
      </div>
  </div>

    </div>

  </section>
```

Mi idea es hacer algo muy parecido a lo que se hace con este editor de  stackoverflow pero a menor escala.

Ir agregando notas (preguntas) en determinada pagina, varias no solo uno, que estas se creen dinamicamente ya sea en el `div id="main-escritos">` .

Alguien me podría guiar.

Saludos.

Comment: realiza una consulta a tu base de datos inmediatamente después de la validación del post, de esa manera agregas los elementos en tu div y si no hay, muestras un mensaje tipo ***se el primero*** o algo así

Comment: Si quieres cargar todo en la misma página puede hacerlo con un `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?> ` en el `<form action="">`. y puedes hacer un inicio de sesión y usar una `$_SESSION['']` con un `isset()` para preguntarte si se ha iniciado sesión. Si se ha iniciado, que te imprima el formulario (o sea, si existe la varibale `$_SESSION[]`), pero si no existe, que te muestre un mensaje con un alert() o algo. Espero te sirva la respuesta

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer todo con javascript y con ajax mandar a una rutina en php para que actualice la Base de Datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomendaria usar ajax para hacer el submit y procesar la informacion a donde desees ejemplo sencillo :

  
    
    
      $(function () {

```
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ejemploPost.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
          //coloca el resultado en un div por id(idDiv)
          document.getElementById('idDiv').innerHTML = data;
        }
      });

    });

  });
</script>
```

**en tu archivo PHP:**

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
$valor1=$_POST['valor1'];
$valor2=$_POST['valor2'];
mysql_query("SQL insert statement.......");
}else { }

?>
```

[Te recomiendo este link](http://wearecoders.net/submit-form-without-page-refresh-with-php-and-ajax/)